# Horizontally centering a flex div with Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a few items inside a div that I can't seem to get to center horizontally using Tailwind - I think it's due to how I'm using flex?

```html
<Row>
  <div class={"flex items-center gap-6"}>
    <div class="text-right">
      <h1 class="text-4xl font-serif">
        <em>Create</em> your account
      </h1>
      <p>We'll have you set up in a few short steps</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-left">
      <Form
        data={{
          name: {
            label: "First Name",
            type: "text",
            required: true,
            errorMessage: "Please enter your first name",
          },
          email: {
            label: "Email",
            type: "email",
            required: true,
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="mt-4 text-center">
    Already registered?{" "}
    <Link
      url="/signin"
      className="text-pink-500 hover:text-pink-500 visited:text-pink-500"
      text="Sign In"
    />
  </div>
</Row>
```

Here's how it looks - the space on the right shouldn't be there

[image]

Comment: maybe use `justify-items-center`, because `items-center` is like saying `align-items: center;` which is vertical centering, not horizontal. if you want to center both ways use `place-items-center` (works in `grid`, but in modern browsers also in flex)... so for me just go for `justify-items-center`

Comment: It looks totally different here https://play.tailwindcss.com/lpUgZZ9Dlg, please make required changes and share the link back to me , and tell what you actually want

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas neither of these routes work unfortunately - they just move the left column up so that's no longer vertically centered. The whole area doesn't shift into the middle.

I wonder if it's something to do with the <Row> above?

Comment: Did you try my link ?